# Днепр или Днипро?

Tags: орфография, топонимика

В Украине переименовали Днепропетровск в **Днiпро**.

Как должно звучать это название на русском?
Не на украинском русском, а на "русском русском".
Если не брызгать ядом, а признать как данность факт переименования и необходимость транскрипции и транслитерации?

Кое-какие мысли есть по ссылке:
http://kp.ua/politics/539681-kazhdyi-fyloloh-zhelaet-znat-dnepr-yly-dnypro

Но тут вот какая штука. Меня совсем не вдохновляет история с написанием "Беларусь", испортившим чувство языка на долгие годы миллионам россиян.
Поэтому появление нового образования "Днипро" просто во имя политических установок принять не могу.

Но тут-то мы сталкиваемся с необходимостью как-то утвердить ***новый*** топоним.
*"Беларусь" никак нельзя было считать топонимом новым, это не переименование, изменение политического статуса само по себе таковым не является.*

Есть три варианта.
~1. Либо не признать переименования вообще и продолжать употреблять чуждое название ("назло мамке уши отморожу"). Всерьез  не рассматриваю.

~2. Либо перенести на новый топоним омонимичное ему название реки, т. е. "перевести" как ***"Днепр"*** (аналогичное имеет место для названия городского футбольного клуба "Днiпро", но он-то и так по реке назван). Могу смириться.

~3. Либо воспользоваться рекомендациями украинских филологов и использовать на русском форму ***Днипро***. Психологически мне такой вариант ближе. Разумеется, не потому что нам его украинские знатоки насаждают (я уже c, прости Господи, "беларускими" устал ругаться), но по подходу, применяемому именно в русском языке.
Беда в другом. Склонять-то как? В украинском — это слово мужского рода. В русском придется или средним делать и склонять вопреки нормам украинского, или не склонять вообще, как Бордо. И тому и другому есть аналоги. Рим и Париж в оригинале — дамы прекрасные, а Бордо он у нас мужского, но не склоняется.

Короче, хочу услышать взвешенный подход.

Comment: На въезде в город знак не демонтировали полностью, сбили буквы правой части слова, оставив ДНЕПР.

Comment: Не было там такого знака. Оставить могли только ДНIПРО. Собственно, это и сделали.

Answer (score 4):

Практика заимствования с украинского языка показывает, что чаще всего для имен собственных используют метод перевода. Петр, а не Петро, "Шахтер", а не "Шахтар", например. Поэтому "Днепр" по мне выглядит наиболее обоснованным. Конечно чаще мы тут видим украинизацию ранее существовавших русских названий и имен, но тем не менее аналогия-то появилась.

Comment: Согласен, в целом - разумно. Но смущает, что такой перевод зачастую объяснялся политикой.

Answer (score 1):

У меня не возникало этого вопроса просто потому, что название привязано к одноимённой реке, у которой есть русское название Днепр. Было бы неестественным по какому-либо правилу разводить название города и реки. Да и склонять название "Днипро" неудобно, не говоря о неизбежном образовании слов типа "днипровитяне" вместо "днепровцы". Соответственно, я сразу предположил, что будет "**Днепр**". Можно, конечно, предполагать и попытки (по политическим причинам) сохранить в русском прежнее наименование города, но практика полного игнорирования самоназваний обычно ограничивается названиями некоторых стран (напр. мы не говорим "Дойчланд", "Беларусь", "Чжунго" вместо "Китая" и т. п.), не распространяясь на названия городов.

Comment: Этнохороним ("топохороним"?) - "днепряне", "днепровцы". Это не проблема. И, разумеется, мы не обязаны следовать навязываемым названиям, если в русском языке есть сложившееся. Но тут-то мы имеем дело с новым названием, не имеющим русского аналога. А я вот не понимаю, почему неудобно разводить". Как раз нежелательность омонимичности топонимов - один из доводов противников переименования (хотя довод, конечно, весьма и весьма спорный).

Answer (score 1):

Да, обсуждается везде, где только можно. 
Но вопрос действительно животрепещущий.

Мне нравится подход Марка Иза. Зачем омонимичные топонимы переводить по-разному?!

Но с другой стороны, нельзя не признать и факта расхождения фонетики в именах латиноамериканских стран и их столиц. Правда из этого факта можно сделать противоположные выводы. Да и вообще стремление быть ближе к оригиналу в век Интернета надо всячески приветствовать. Меньше путаницы, во всяком случае там, где это не противоречит сложившейся практике.

Если бы не трудности склонения стоял бы за Днипро. А с учетом всех составляющих - Днепр.

Answer (score 0):

> Короче, хочу услышать взвешенный подход.

Взвешенный подход такой, что язык функционирует не в сферическом вакууме, а в некотором человеческом обществе. Современная латынь функционирует в среде филологов, фармацевтов, юристов, историков. В этой среде есть свои сообщества - и именно эти сообщества будут определять изменения в современной латыни. Так же и с русским языком.

По-русски сабжевый город называется "Днепропетровск" и изменения в русском языке будут определяться сообществами, в которых функционирует русский язык. Так получилось, что в настоящий момент таких сообществ много, а значит возможен плюрализм в названии Днепропетровска. В географическом атласе на бумаге может быть применено одно название, а в Википедии - иное. Сейчас подобное происходит с топонимом "Таллин" [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Таллин](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD) - в некоторых же сообществах пишут "Таллинн" - http://www.tallinn.ee/rus и могут наказывать за правильное написание этого русского слова.

Название Днепропетровска тоже будет разным в разных русскоязычных сообществах.

> а признать как данность факт переименования и необходимость транскрипции и транслитерации?

Если так, то тогда нужно полностью подчиниться решению переименовавшего органа и следовать его рекомендациям. В случае неясностей - направить запрос переименователям и поступать уж тогда так, как они этого требуют, а не сочинять своих вариантов. Так прямо и спросить: "Как нам называть этот город по-русски?" - и подчиниться указаниям переименователей (если признать как данность факт переименования).

Comment: Вопрос поставлен о "русском русском", а не о "русском, практикуемом в Украине", поэтому и аналогия с эстонско-русским вариантом русского названия Таллина находится в стороне от заданного вопроса. Это всё имеет регионально ограниченное хождение. Мне попадался и официальный документ об особенностях использования русского языка для деловой переписки в Белоруссии, но его содержание никоим образом не может и не должно влиять на русский язык в России - это касается только разновидности русского, используемой в Белоруссии, где русский имеет статус государственного, чего нет в Эстонии или в Украине.

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, что вы понимаете именно под "русским русским"?

Comment: Условно говоря, это то же, что "британский английский" по отношению к американскому, индийскому, австралийскому и др. "английским", которые различаются в ряде аспектов. Например, в Великобритании никогда не называют футбол "сокером" (soccer), как в Америке. По сходным причинам нет оснований называть Таллин "Таллинном", если где-то так стали писать в русскоязычных газетах несколько лет назад, тем более в стране, где русский язык не является государственным.

Comment: Разве что очень условно говоря. Тем более что это вопрос топонимики, поэтому будут оказывать давление иные факторы. Может оказаться, что и в "условном" русском русском" могут быть различные варианты, пример: Надпись "Таллинн" на дорожном указателе в Псковской области.

Comment: Да, для того условности и заключаются в кавычки, чтобы употреблённое наименование не искали в справочниках. А что вас смущает? Есть язык, а есть его диалекты, которые иногда дипломатично величают " таким-то английским". Я встречал и наименование English English, намеренно употреблённое вместо British English представителем страны, давшей миру английский язык, и его скептицизм в той конкретной ситуации можно было понять - сказано было для выразительности, в напоминание о том, откуда взялся английский.

Comment: Что касается дорожного указателя, то случай позорный - да, ходило в 90-х и от наших газетчиков такое веяние; да мало ли курьёзов на табличках с названиеми улиц? Я и в Мариинском театре видел табличку с ошибкой в английском слове "музыка".

Comment: Смущает этот "русский русский", хотя я сам так иронично выражаюсь. Вот ещё я сейчас погуглил топоним "Цхинвали" на сайте vesti.ru - после августа 2008 года стали писать "Цхинвал". На этом же сайте! Как бы непонятно, какой из этих русских языков русский русский, а какой русский иной. А на tvrain.ru пишут "Цхинвали". Получается плюрализм, о котором я писал в своём ответе. Разные сообщества будут использовать разные названия.

Comment: В данном случае вмешалась политика (убрать грузинское окончание), не знаю даже, происходило ли официальное переименование. В российских газетах "по-новому" давно пишут. Это из той же серии, что "на Украине" или "в Украине". Я по отношению к нынешнему государству предпочитаю второй вариант, причём по языковым соображениям - в отличие от значения бывшей территории России, "на" которой что-то произрастает и т. п.

Comment: @Alex_ander и user471, вы оба сейчас не учитываете одну вещь. Надо четко разделять "Таллинн", "Кыргызстан", "Беларусь" с одной стороны и  "Бишкек", "Петербург-Петроград-Ленинград",  "Мумбай"  и прочие "Буркина Фасо" с другой. Первое - навязанная русскому языку *орфография*, русскому языку чуждая, поэтому встречает активное сопротивление. Более того - замешанная на политике. Хотя иногда и приживается. Второе - переименование или появление новых топонимов. Тут политики - если и есть,  необходимый минимум. Вопрос чисто топтнимический. "Днипро" - это переименование. (см. далее)

Comment: Вы же оба, при всей разности подходов, в той или иной степени пытаетесь свести дело к политическим разговорам. В конце конуов Alex_ander  приходит к выводам, которые от политики почти своюбодны, поэтому его позиция мне куда ближе.

Comment: Да, *русский русский* - это, так скажем ,"российский русский". А не украинский русский, который при всем сходстве имеет отличия и несет следы политической конъюнктуры. Термин - именно что аналог британского, американского или австралийского английского. Это непростой вопрос, британцы вон не кичатся своим правом иметь собственные названия американских топонимов. Ну так и американцы их не навязывают. Правда, там и случаи расхождения единичные.

Comment: Вопрос был о возможной замене топонима "Днепропетровск" в связи некими событиями. То же было и с топонимом "Таллин" - где-то, в какой-то группе товарищей появляется желание модифицировать топоним. Русский язык, как система, как-то реагирует на это волевое решение. Например на попытку введения в русский язык топонима Джохар-гала. Может быть примет "Днипро", как велят модификаторы, а может быть и нет. Вот в русском языке так вышло, что названия столиц Мексики и Бразилии не одноимённы названиям государств. Ну, бывает. Тут трудно предугадать реакцию.

Comment: *То же было и с топонимом "Таллин"* - нет. Замены топонима (переименования) не было. Была чисто орфографическая заморочка по поводу написания. И потом, я уже сказал, разковор о связи с некоторыи событиями - это политика, которую надо гнать отсюда поганой метлой. Топонимика должна принимать ситуацию как данность. Событие только одно: "переименование" и его последствия.  "Причинами"  (читай: политической целесообразностью) можно оправдать что угодно.